# I need to do research on any topic related to Quality assurance. Which topic would be good?

Tags: test-management, qa-role, quality-assurance, qa-process

The topic should not be vague and something which is difficult to achieve. Simple and conclusive topic would be the best.Please suggest some.

Comment: This is much too opinion-based a question for this forum. Please see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about asking good questions

Answer (score 2):

I have a few topics of my own interest:

- How to determine the effectiveness of a test automation case? Not all test cases catch bugs, some test cases are ineffective; how to find them so that effort can be saved from maintaining ineffective test cases.
- How to effectively implement static code analysis? There are various static code analysis tools, which ones to choose?
- How to effectively implement BDD? BDD has been around for some time, and many have attempted to implement it; it does not work for all of them, why?
- How to effectively organize software development / testing cycle? How to develop, test, deploy codes in an efficient environment? One factor to consider is: how to use virtual environment as a development / test platform.

Answer (score 1):

Prachi, Welcome to the SQA and Testing StackExchange community.

If you want to do some research. Then I would embrace this as a chance to add to the SQA body of knowledge for yourself and the community with something not commonly thought about.

Maybe this research topic might be new:

- What are the fundamental trait differences between SW Developers and
  the SQA engineers that test their code?

I am not talking about technical skills, more what are those soft skills that are dominant in each party (developer and tester).

You could start by finding some developers and testers that are willing to complete a survey for comparison.

Example survey sources (of course more could be added here):

- the survey connected with the "Strengths finder 2.0" book by Tom
  Rath
- a Myers–Briggs Type Indicator test
- or a survey that you could come up with (you probably have ideas about differences)

The important principle here is get the data and make some conclusions with it.

All the best to you, Remember to post your results back to StackExchange!